# Loose coupling, accessing class properties

Tags: c#, interface, .net-datatable

I'm trying to get a better understanding of decoupling methods. Right now, I have this method:

```
private bool ContainsLegalFirstName(DataRow row, string legalFirstNameColumn)
{
    return row.Table.Columns.Contains(legalFirstNameColumn)
        && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(row[legalFirstNameColumn].ToString());
}
```

I was thinking about changing the `DataRow` to an `IDataRecord` and adding an `IListSource` parameter and passing in the `DataTable`, but then the problem is I can't access the columns of the `DataTable` from the `IListSource`. Any suggestions or is what I have good enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `DataRow` does not implement `IDataRecord`, you would have to pass an adapter that wraps the row and implements the interface. Also, passing an `IListSource` would only help if it always returned a `ITypedList` (which is not guaranteed) which you could then query for available properties by name. But what would be the advantage of all that?

In my opinion, the parameter types are alright. We are still talking about a private helper method, not one that needs to be accessible using all kinds of interfaces. There are, however, some things that I might change:

1. - Either: Rename the method to represent that it actually does not care about the legal first name. You could currently rename it to `ContainsLegalLastName` without any change in behaviour.
   - Or: Remove the `legalFirstNameColumn` and get that value from somewhere else (some configuration, `const`, …).
2. Unless you decide to remove the column name parameter and get the column name from an instance variable, make the method `static`. It currently does not use any state at all.

Comment: **Rename the method to represent that it actually does not care about the legal first name** - Why do you say that?

**Remove the legalFirstNameColumn and get that value from somewhere else (some configuration, const, …).** - When I call this method, I pass a const to it. That const varies depending on the DataTable that is being validated by this method (there are 5 of them with different column names). Is that okay?

Comment: Yes, but I think you could still rename the method, because the fact that you are checking for the last name does not really matter, since the correct column name is determined outside the method in question.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. So maybe rename to ContainsColumn() or something and pass the column name?

Comment: Yes, sorry if I was not clear enough in my answer. :)